# How to align disorder region and sequence in a larger scale (python)

Tags: python, alignment, bioinformatics

So this is a follow up to my previous question. Thanks to @mdml. My previous question about How to align and compare two elements (sequence) in a list using python have been solved. Here is the code that I'm using  (Code credit to mdml):

```
# Parse the file which was already split into split_list
lines = open("seq.txt")
for list in lines:
    split_list = list.split()
header = "".join(split_list[0:2])
seq = split_list[2]
disorder = split_list[4]

# Create the new disorder string
new_disorder = ["Disorder: Posi R"]
for i, x in enumerate(disorder):
    if x == "X":
        # Appends of the form: "AminoAcid Position"
        new_disorder.append("{} {}".format(i, seq[i]))

new_disorder = " ".join(new_disorder)

# Output the modified file
open("seq2.txt", "w").write( "\n".join([header, seq, new_disorder]))
```

This code work perfectly with my example which is:

> 103L   Sequence:   MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL   Disorder:   ----------------------------------XXXXXX-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------XX

However when I use this code for multiple protein sequence. It still work, but only last protein sequence and it's disordered region showed up in the new file. What should I do to fix it?

Here are some more protein sequence:

> 102M   Sequence:   MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEADVAGHGQDILIRLFKSHPETLEKFDRFKHLKTEAEMKASEDLKKAGVTVLTALGAILKKKGHHEAELKPLAQSHATKHKIPIKYLEFISEAIIHVLHSRHPGNFGADAQGAMNKALELFRKDIAAKYKELGYQG   Disorder:   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   103L   Sequence:   MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL   Disorder:   ----------------------------------XXXXXX-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------XX
>   103M   Sequence:   MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEADVAGHGQDILIRLFKSHPETLEKFDRFKHLKTEAEMKASEDLKKAGVTVLTALGAILKKKGHHEAELKPLAQSHATKHKIPIKYLEFISEAIIHVLHSRHPGNFGADAQGAMNKALELFRKDIAAKYKELGYQG   Disorder:   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   104L   Sequence:   MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSAAELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL   Disorder:   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------XX

Comment: Are you running this on multiple input files, or one file that contains multiple protein sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to append to the file, you are overwriting each time:

Use `open("seq2.txt", "a")`

```
 open("seq2.txt", "a").write( "\n".join([header, seq, new_disorder]))
```

Also better to use `with` to open a file as it close the file automatically:

```
with open("seq2.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write( "\n".join([header, seq, new_disorder]))
```

You should not use `list` as a variable name either, you are shadowing the builtin `list`
This code should work but it would be better to append each sequence to a list and write when finished:

```
with open("seq2.txt") as lines:
    for l in lines:
        split_list = l.split()

        header = "".join(split_list[0:2])
        seq = split_list[2]
        disorder = split_list[4]

        # Create the new disorder string
        new_disorder = ["Disorder: Posi R"]
        print new_disorder
        for i, x in enumerate(disorder): # nest your for loop to process each line
            if x == "X":
                # Appends of the form: "AminoAcid Position"
                new_disorder.append("{} {}".format(i, seq[i]))

        new_disorder = " ".join(new_disorder)


        with open("seq2.txt", "a+") as f: # write to file after each process
            f.write( "\n".join([header, seq, new_disorder]))
```

Using a list:

```
total_seq=[]
with open("out.txt") as lines:
    for l in lines:
        split_list = l.split()

        header = "".join(split_list[0:2])
        seq = split_list[2]
        disorder = split_list[4]

        # Create the new disorder string
        new_disorder = ["Disorder: Posi R"]
        print new_disorder
        for i, x in enumerate(disorder):
            print disorder
            if x == "X":
                # Appends of the form: "AminoAcid Position"
                new_disorder.append("{} {}".format(i, seq[i]))

        new_disorder = " ".join(new_disorder)

        total_seq.append([header, seq, new_disorder])
with open("seq2.txt", "a") as f:
    for seq in total_seq:
        f.write( "\n".join(seq))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But unfortunately I still only got the last line

Comment: @user3817527,can you indent your code as you are using it, I will be able to  see what else is wrong and the input as it is in your file

Comment: I believe I've already indent my code, I am sorry but can you be more specific? I'm new in programing, sorry.

Comment: your code as posted has syntax errors, you need to add the code exactly as you have you locally, indent your `if x=="X"` etc..

Comment: Thank you. I believe I fixed it

Comment: can you post a couple more lines from your sequence and is the sequence you have posted all on one line in your txt file?

Comment: But I'm afraid that I got another question. So your code have fixed my problem. And I've edit and post more protein sequence example in my question. Say that there is some sequence with disordered region which is indicated by 'X', however, there are some other sequence that don't have disordered region. I want to ignore them. Is there any methods to filter out the protein sequence that without any disordered region?

Comment: Is there something missing in those lines that we can check for?

Comment: So in the example I posted under my question. For 102M protein sequence. There is only '--------------' but no 'X' in it. That means there is disorder region. And I want to ignore such protein sequence

Comment: just use `if not X in l:continue` before you split